# Why isn't the new execution policy set from PowerShell visible from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, executionpolicy

I have used the following code to successfully get the execution policy:

```csharp
using (var powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powerShellInstance.AddCommand("Get-ExecutionPolicy");
    Collection<PSObject> obj = powerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

I have used the following code to set the execution policy:

```csharp
using (var powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powerShellInstance.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddArgument("ByPass");
    powerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

The problem is when I set the execution policy from PowerShell, the change is not visible in C#.  If I set the execution policy from C# then the change is visible.

Consider the following scenario:

- C# gets the execution policy `Unrestricted`.
- PowerShell sets the execution policy to `Bypass`.
- C# gets the execution policy `Unrestricted`.
- C# sets the execution policy to `Bypass`.
- C# gets the execution policy `Bypass`.

Comment: The Setting is stored in the registry under HKLM | HKCU \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Scope***!

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope MachinePolicy
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope UserPolicy
```

I *believe* the default scope is `Process` (hence your issue)

Comment: This should be true. However, the help for `Set-ExecutionPolicy` says the default is different (`LocalMachine`), but I really doubt this one - it's a risk high enough to throw set-executionpolicy with machine by default. It's also possible that failing to set local machine policy the cmdlet changed scope to process.

Comment: Great, I have changed scope to CurrentUser and then tested, working fine.